# Android writing to a CSV file via OpenCsv

Tags: java, android, file-io, csv

I try to write to a Csv file via:

```
mFileWriter = new FileWriter(
        "/sdcard/program/file");

mCsvWriter = new CSVWriter(mFileWriter);
```

At the moment it throws an exception that the file doesn't exist.
It's true that the file doesn't exist. What's the easiest way to create the file?

Answer (score 2):

Does the FILE not exist, or the DIRECTORY it's supposed to go into?

If you want to create a directory structure, you can always do

```
File file = new File("/full/path/to/file");
file.mkdirs();
```

This will create any path leading up to this file that doesn't exist yet.

I suppose the missing quotes around your file name are a typo?

Comment: Yes, the missing quotes are a typo.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. 
file.mkdirs() returns false on my end.

Comment: From the documentation: "Returns
true if the necessary directories have been created, false if the target directory already exists or one of the directories can not be created." 1. Did it already exist? 2. Do you have the permissions to create the structure? 3. Are you trying to create a directory with the same name as an existing file?